# How to detect recyclerview’s scrolling outside it bounds?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scroll

Is there a way to detect that user is trying to scroll recyclerview and actual scrolling is not happened? For example, the vertical recyclerview is at its top position, and user tries to scroll it up.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah , you can detect the scrolling behaving using onScroll function of recycler view .

```
 recyclerView
                .addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView,
                                           int dx, int dy) {
                        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                        lastVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager
                                .findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                        if (!loading
                                && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                            // Do something

                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

As you can see above , (linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();) gives you the last visible position , once the user try to scroll the recycler view , it tends to change the last visible position .

Even dx gives you the int: The amount of horizontal scroll and dy (int) gives you the amount of vertical scroll . 
This callback will also be called if visible item range changes after a layout calculation. In that case, dx and dy will be 0.